# IOS Parsing multiple JSON feeds

Tags: objective-c, json, ios6

I'm doing a project where I have website from which I'm parsing a JSON data. The problem is that it's a restaurant chain so there are a lot of cities and each city might have multiple restaurants. Right now for the sake of design I'm creating a new method for each address which I know is bad.

```
- (void)fetchRSSFeedWithCompletion:(void (^)(FeedChannel *obj, NSError *err))block
{

NSString *formattedUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.sodexo.fi/ruokalistat/output/daily_json/441/%@/fi", [self currentDate]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:formattedUrl];

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

FeedChannel *channel = [[FeedChannel alloc] init];

SMConnection *connection = [[SMConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req];

[connection setCompletionBlock:^(FeedChannel *obj, NSError *err) {
    if (!err) {
        [self setTopSongsCacheDate:[NSDate date]];
        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:obj toFile:cachePath];
    }
    block(obj, err);
}];
[connection setJsonRootObject:channel];
[connection start];
}
```

What would be the best way to approach this? Do I create a class which has all the adresses and then call them? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having the addresses dynamically added to your servers. Then you should not store them on a device. So, to answer your specific question :

> Do I create a class which has all the adresses and then call them?

I think you should ***avoid this unless you have static addresses*** which won't change in future.

I have accomplished this kind of thing in one of my project. Here's what I did. (**May be not the BEST approach, but I got it working nice and smooth**):

For addresses you need to have a separate web service. Which will return you only the JSON Array of addresses (Which of course, you can display in an intermediate TableView)

Then, based on the selection by user (or whatever in your case), you can call the web service which returns you all the restaurants details for that Address.

**Note:** Your web services should return minimal data. You can always have detailed data (like , reviews about those restaurants) in another separate web service. ***Avoid dumping all your data into a single call (as and when possible)***

May not be a perfect solution. But, I hope this helps you, to have some idea.

### EDIT

As you can't edit the web services provided to you, There are very less chances to improve the approach. Though You can have all the codes for restaurants manually and create a database (OR you can just use .plist file for that, as the amount of data won't be large in size).

**Points that can help you:**

- The main part is you must have your data (city -> restaurants)
  organized.
- Use [`NSOperation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) for performing web service call as an
  independent operation in [`NSOperationQueue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) just to make the process well organized.

At View Level, whatever you want to show, it's your call.

Comment: Problem is that the web service is not in my control. Here's address to one restaurant http://www.sodexo.fi/ruokalistat/output/daily_json/441/2013/4/16/fi and here's to another http://www.sodexo.fi/ruokalistat/output/daily_json/472/2013/4/16/fi So the only thing that changes is that number after /daily_json/

Comment: All the data I can get from there is in those links so what do you mean by manipulating it? Yes it's a restaurant chain here in Finland which provides JSON data. I'm doing this just for learning purposes. Yes they are tags for restaurants.

Comment: So, Restaurants `441` and `472` are restaurants at same location, right?

Comment: They must have the web service for retrieving all the restaurants codes, else how would others know that there is some new branch of it opened somewhere?

Comment: Tags like `441`, `472`, `525` and `526` are restaurants in one city. Then tags like `429`, `444`, and `485` are restaurants in other. No logic, no special service to know them, just manual work. So basically I need to have selection of the city and then for example have segmented control to load proper addresses based on the city.